# Convert Blob String to Numpy Image on Backend

Tags: javascript, flask

So I have a frontend that has a box class that stores x and y in an image and when the user hits a predict button the image,x,y are sent to the backend where a flask app takes them and then converts the image to a numpy array for tensorflow. The image is encoded as utf8 however I can't seem to have it load or decode it with opencv or tensorflow's encode jpeg. Any help would be nice.

Frontend:

```js
  async predict() {
    //Get the image of the box
    const response = await fetch(document.getElementById('image').src);
    const data = await response.text();

    const response2 = await fetch('/predict', {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        x: this.x,
        y: this.y,
        data,
      }),
    })

    const json = await response2.json();

    return json;
  }
```

```py
@app.route("/predict", methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    #get image from blob image
    #Get image from url 
    args = request.get_json()
    x = args['x']
    y = args['y']
    #Get url but filter the blob: part
    image = args['data']

    #Decode string to image here.
    
    #read utf-8 encoded string into image
    return json({"prediction":enhance.predict(image,enhance.model,x,y)})
```

Comment: Did you try `response.blob()` instead of `response.text()` in your javascript? Then you can use base64 encoding and then json stringify.

Comment: @Nechoj when you send a blob from client to server where is that stored? Because it does not send the blob to the server in the json keyed on "data". So where would blob be stored if it sent it at all.

Comment: No sorry, I meant you first convert the blob into a base64 encoded string, this string you put inside the object (data) that gets json stringified and this stringifies object you sent to the server in the body. Then on the server, you base64-decode the string received inside the object (=data) and this results in the binary image on the server side.

Comment: See example below (not sure what `enhance.predict(image,enhance.model,x,y)` exactly does ...)

Answer (score 0):

Using base64 encoding:

```
  async predict() {
    //Get the image of the box
    const response = await fetch(document.getElementById('image').src);
    let data = await response.arrayBuffer();
    data = btoa(data);  // base64 encode

    const response2 = await fetch('/predict', {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        x: this.x,
        y: this.y,
        data,
      }),
    })

    const json = await response2.json();

    return json;
  }
```

```
import base64
@app.route("/predict", methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    #get image from blob image
    #Get image from url 
    args = request.get_json()
    x = args['x']
    y = args['y']
    #Get url but filter the blob: part
    image = args['data']
    
    # base64 decode
    image = base64.b64decode(image)
    
    return json({"prediction": enhance.predict(image, enhance.model, x, y)})
```

Comment: That just stores the bytes object. if you decode the image the only thing returned is b'[object Blob]'

Comment: Right, the blob is a wrapper for an arrayBuffer, and this is what you need. I fixed it.

Comment: How do I get that into a standard image format for python like a numpy array or a PIL image object?

Comment: If it was a byte array image: `img = np.fromstring(base64.b64decode(image), dtype=np.uint8)`. Depending on what the shape of the original image was, you could then do a `np.reshape(img, shape)`. This way you can restore e.g. a 3 channel color image. Maybe it a good idea to send the original shape together with the data inside the ajax call.

Comment: If you are using Opencv, you could do `image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(base64.b64decode(image), dtype=np.uint8),
                                                      cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)` This would work also when the original image was `jpg`.

Comment: If you're using Pillow: `img =io.BytesIO(np.fromstring(base64.b64decode(image), dtype=np.uint8))` + `pic =  PIL.Image.open(picture_stream)`. Should work with jpg, too.